# How to modify TensorFlow code to accept samples for prediction on Google Cloud ML?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I tried to create a model on Google Cloud ML after exporting my trained model from Cloud Storage but the error I got was:

`Create Version failed. Model validation failed: SavedModel must contain exactly one metagraph with tag: serve For more information on how to export Tensorflow SavedModel, seehttps://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model.`

So I only have one TensorFlow `.add_meta_graph_and_variables()` in my training. Am I supposed to make another one to handle new inputs? I don't fully understand the process for creating a serving meta graph and how I can set up my code to evaluate a single instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are using core TensorFlow, you should export a separate prediction graph. See:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/tensorflowcore/trainer/model.py

If you are using the Estimator API, simply use Experiment and pass in an export function.  I strongly suggest using Estimator/Experiment rather than core TensorFlow

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/estimator/trainer/task.py#L43

Comment: Just to add to this answer, be sure the signature_def_map has an entry with the key 'serve' (aka tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY if you like to type a lot and are pedantic about constants) and be sure to set tags = [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING].

In TF 1.4 you'll be able to use [`simple_save`][https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/saved_model/python/saved_model/utils.py#L28]

Comment: @rhaertel80 Is TF 1.4 fully supported in GCP? If not... any idea? :)
I understand that it is not yet (at least the corresponding runtime version webpage mentions just 1.0 and 1.2), but I have read some comment over here about coming "soon"...
On the other hand, and on our end, we have successfully trained and deployed a model with TF 1.4 on GCP (with the --runtime-version=HEAD option) and we can even do online predictions but not batch ones with the deployed model, which is a bit confusing)

Comment: If all goes well, TF 1.4 will be available next week across all of Cloud ML Engine endpoints, including batch prediction.

Comment: What was the error message you got with batch prediction when using HEAD? If this is a bug, I'm happy to report it (although, please note that we don't officially support HEAD).

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier, I've been on some GCP training course :)
This is the error we were getting for every entry we had in the batch files: `Failed to load the model due to bad model data. tags: ['serve'] No op named HashTableV2 in defined operations.`
If need be, I can send via e-mail details on the project and job name for your debugging should it be needed.
And yes, aware of the official support of the HEAD (well, lack thereof :) No worries.